# AWS SES, Mail plugin and Grails configuration

Tags: grails, amazon-web-services, grails-plugin, grails-2.0, amazon-ses

I'm trying to set up the Mail plugin with my SES credentials, but I am obviously missing something because I keep getting this error:

```
Class: javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException
Message: No provider for aws
```

I've added the following to my Config.groovy:

```
grails {
    mail {
       host = "email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"
       port = 465
       username = "XXXXXXXXX"
       password = "YYYYYYYYY"
       props = [
            'mail.transport.protocol': 'aws',
            'mail.aws.class': 'com.amazonaws.services.simpleemail.AWSJavaMailTransport',
            'mail.aws.user': 'WWWWWWWWWWWW',
            'mail.aws.password': 'ZZZZZZZZZZZ'
        ]
    }
 }
```

I've been looking through all the possible tutorials, half of them were from the time SES didn't support SMTP, thats why I have the class reference from the maven repo.

Does anyone know how I can configure this?

Comment: I guess nobody knows how to do it :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what I have been using successfully -

```
grails {
    mail {
        host = "email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"
        port = 587
        username = "smtp user name"
        password = "smtp password"
        props = ["mail.smtp.starttls.enable":"true",
                    "mail.smtp.port":"587"]
    }
}
```

Let me know if the above works

Comment: I actually had to swap to Gaemes plugin, aws plugin, which enables an easy integration with SES and S3, but i'had tried your solution and it worked correctly ... a little late my response, srry

Comment: It worked for me including "mail.smtp.auth":"true" also